# What should be on a DVT (Design Verification Test) checklist?

Tags: checklist

Despite doing a Google search and finding [this from Avanthon Engineering](http://www.avanthon.com/dvt_checklist.php) (link now dead, see [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20060616183148/http://avanthon.com/dvt_checklist.php)), I haven't found a good checklist.  Theirs is more for board bring up than making sure a design really works before it goes to production.  I'm thinking of checks such as

- Check at high/low voltage
- Check at high/low temperature
- Check more than one unit
- Check signal integrity on clocks and other critical signals

In this case the design is an analog one.  But since I mainly do digital designs, suggestions there are welcome.  I have a mental checklist, but I'm sure I could use a written one.

Comment: A DVT is tailored to a design. What is the design?

Comment: Don't just check at high and low temperatures and voltages, but sweep through them.  Not every temperature / voltage dependence is monotonic.

Comment: Community Wiki is a moderator option only. This is because users often use CW to keep poor questions. We will watch this and hope that we get quality answers. If many poor opinionated answers with nothing else pop up we will have to close out the question and have another go at opening a better one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A DVT should cover everything you promise to your customer in the data sheet. Ideally, you also have made a spec long before you've written the data sheet, and the spec may even have more details than the data sheet because you don't want all the little things to be published.

When you do the DVT, you test each and every parameter you specified before or while you designed the gadget. It's as simple (and as much work) as this.

Comment: We usually test to the SPEC as well as a common standard that includes things like I/O protection, short circuit, over voltage conditions, etc., so that we don't have to include them in every spec for each product.  Every DC product must survive reversal of the power leads, for example, so that goes into the global requirements doc.